# Reading GlobSnow HDF4 files in R

Tags: r, gis, hdf

I am trying to read .hdr files in R. The files come from GlobSnow and can be found at 
http://www.globsnow.info/swe/archive_v2.0/2013/L3A_daily_SWE_HDF/

I have used the gdalUtils package, which seems to work for MODIS data, but is not working for GlobSnow data. I have tried this:

```
sd <- get_subdatasets("GlobSnow_SWE_L3A_20130101_v2.0.hdf")
gdal_translate(sd[2], sds=T, dst_dataset = "hdftrial.tif")
```

However it returns NULL.

I have also tried installing gdal through homebrew, but am unsure how to make that work in R. I opened the data in HDFview and the data seems to be right. There just doesn't seem to be an easy way to access this data in R. I am hoping to get a raster or a matrix from the .hdf file.

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL` comes out for me too, just follow up with `raster("hdftrial.tif")` and it loads the raster in no problem. `NULL` comes up because you have no subdatasets (sds), you are intentionally only calling a single dataset, however it appears that the hdf does not read in the subdatasets if you do not declare.

```
library(gdalUtils)
library(raster)
sd <- get_subdatasets("c:/_LOCALdata/GlobSnow_SWE_L3A_20130101_v2.0.hdf")
gdal_translate(sd[2], dst_dataset = "hdftrial.tif")

plot(raster("hdftrial.tif"))
```

When you use gdal_translate to pull each individual dataset they are both there, it just throws NULL if there are not "subdatasets".

From `gdal_translate`:

```
 if (output_Raster) {
        if (missing(sds)) {
            return(brick(dst_dataset))
        }
        else {
            if (!sds) {
                return(brick(dst_dataset))
            }
            else {
                return(NULL)
            }
        }
    }
    else (return(NULL))
```

> > Update:

```
gdal_translate("c:/_LOCALdata/GlobSnow_SWE_L3A_20130101_v2.0.hdf", sds=T, of="GTiff", dst_dataset = "hdftrial.tif")
```

You do not require the get_subdatasets, as it does it internally. By declaring sds=T it will create an individual file for each subdataset. It still throws the `NULL`, trying to decipher why. You will get a file with _#.tif for each subdataset that exists within the dataset.